# How to startup PM2 with multiple instances

Tags: node.js, typescript, parameters, cron, pm2

I am running my nodejs code via PM2. For my project I need multiple instances of nodejs that running the same code. So I created a next script "myscript.sh":

```
cd ~/myproject    
PM2_HOME='.pm2_1' /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 start dist/app.js -- id=1 token=xxx isMaster=true
PM2_HOME='.pm2_2' /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 start dist/app.js -- id=1 token=yyy isMaster=false
. . .
PM2_HOME='.pm2_x' /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 start dist/app.js -- id=1 token=zzz isMaster=false
```

It works when I run it via CLI like `bash myscript.sh`, but it doesn't work via crontab:

```
@reboot bash /home/user/myproject/myscript.sh
```

or

```
* * * * * bash /home/user/myproject/myscript.sh
```

Also I tried to use `pm2 startup` but it doesn't work with the `PM2_HOME='..'` parameter, no matter what I set to `PM2_HOME`, like **.pm2_1**, it still creates environment like /home/user/myproject/**.pm2**. Seems like `pm2 startup` works for the single instances only.

**So my question how can I run myscript.sh via crontab?**

I don't know if it relevant my code is written in TS. On localhost I run it like this:

```
npm start -- id=1 token=zzz isMaster=false
```

where start is set in package.json:

```
"start": "npm run build && node dist/app"
"build": "rimraf dist && tsc"
```

**Please notice** that

1. Every instance should get different parameters
2. Solution should work for the startup case, like the app should startup with a machine start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have PM2 run multiple instances of your node app you'll want to use [clustered mode](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/).

See the docs here: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/

For example, you can use this command to start 4 instances of your app:

```
pm2 start app.js -i 4
```

--- EDIT ---

For providing different input parameters per process I don't think there is any easy way to do that with PM2.

An alternative is to create a new JavaScript/TypeScript file as your entry point. Have that entry point create multiple [child processes](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/child_process.html), each of which is your application. Then you could pass in different parameters for each.

Comment: But what about parameters that I need to pass? Please notice they are different from instance to instance.

Comment: @Rougher I hadn't noticed the changing parameters. Thanks for the clarification. Do you need PM2? If not maybe you should create a node app that runs multiple instances of your node app as [child processes](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/child_process.html).

Comment: I am not sure how it works exactly, if you can publish some code for my case it will be great. Also still I will have a problem with scheduling, no? I need this app to startup on machine start.

Comment: You could use PM2 to start your primary process, then your primary process can start child processes. If your root process is solid and you know it won't crash then it can handle restarting any crashed child processes. Keep the root process simple.

Check out the `fork` function: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_processforkmodulepath-args-options

Comment: looks like your idea should work for me. What should be parameters for my in the fork function? Detached or not, for example? Why Fork and not Spawn? My nodes should run infinitely, so what should be more optimal to RAM and CPU?

Comment: The description in the docs for fork starts with this statement: `The child_process.fork() method is a special case of child_process.spawn() used specifically to spawn new Node.js processes.` You can use spawn for similar results, but fork provides an easy communication channel between the child and parent process. I'm not sure if fork vs spawn have any difference in CPU and RAM usage. I'm guessing it's equivalent.

Comment: Of course, I saw this documentation, but I remind you that I don't actually need a communication between parent and its children, therefore I am asking.

Answer (score 3):

Why use PM2_HOME var? PM2_HOME var is usefull if you need multiple instance of PM2 daemon.

What you need, if i understand well, is running many instance of your script. This can be done with the same PM2 daemon!

To achieve this just do this, assuming you use linux box.

1 - Start all your instances of your same script with different parameters:

```
pm2 -n "Script 1" start /my/script.js -- param1=xxx param2=111
pm2 -n "Script 2" start /my/script.js -- param1=yyy param2=222
pm2 -n "Script 3" start /my/script.js -- param1=zzz param2=333
```

2 - Save your pm2 configuration:

```
pm2 save
```

3 - Enable pm2 startup hook:

```
pm2 startup
```

4 You are done! You can add new instance if needed, just type the `pm2 save` command to register new instances.