# Start multiple PM2 in the same server

Tags: pm2

How to start multiple pm2 in the server? I want to separate the UAT and production environment in the same server.
I read the guideline from pm2 but where could I change the PM2_HOME value? The pub.sock and rpc.sock are not found in the .pm2 folder. Should I create them manually? And what is the command for different PM2? Thanks

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/specifics/

Tried to follow the guideline from here but not exactly what I want

[https://pureinfotech.com/create-custom-environment-variables-windows-10/#:~:text=To%20create%20Environment%20Variables%20on%20Windows%2011%20(and%2010)%2C,%2C%20and%20click%20%E2%80%9COK.%E2%80%9D](https://pureinfotech.com/create-custom-environment-variables-windows-10/#:%7E:text=To%20create%20Environment%20Variables%20on%20Windows%2011%20(and%2010)%2C,%2C%20and%20click%20%E2%80%9COK.%E2%80%9D)

Comment: You could just create a bash script that sets the environment tables and run the pm2 start command afterward. If you set environment tables in a bash script, it will only be applied for that specific bash script.

Comment: I want to add prefix to pm2 command to avoid someone stop all the services accidentally.

Comment: You can separate the apps if you define different names for them. You could start your production environment by using `pm2 start server.js --name=production` and your UAT environment with `pm2 start server.js --name=uat`. You can then stop them by using `pm2 stop production` or `pm2 stop uat`.

Comment: But "pm2 stop all" will stop both uat and production application which I want to prevent this case.

Comment: Then you could try to execute the pm2 command through different users. Each user has its own unique pm2 session and then you could have a user called uat and another one called production. Depending on the user, you are logged in you can execute pm2 stop all

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need starting multiple PM2 daemons?

If you need to start multiple instance of same script but with differntes environements, you don't.

PM2 is built to star multiple app/script/process.

If you goal is starting same script with different environment, start process with diffrent environment.

You cal aloso read one of my past post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76900896/8807231